# Access Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, vps, centos6, laravel-5.7

I just installed lamp on cent os 6.5 and installed laravel.

I added .htaccess to root directory in laravel app with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now when I want to access domain-name.com/phpmyadmin/ I get `Access Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server`

How can I resolve that?

Without laravel it was working.

Comment: I think it's not problem of your `.htaccess`

Comment: Can you share your `route` file

Comment: Just as some thoughts, I'd point my virtual host file to `/path/to/laravel-application/public` instead of adding an .htaccess file to the application root. I'd also change where phpmyadmin lives from a folder to a subdomain (like database.example.org)

Comment: its empty, fresh laravel installation nothing changed besides this htaccess code to open public directory instead of root